# how to loop lapply function in R

Tags: r, function, simulation, lapply, rpart

I have two large lists,

1. imputemodel with 1000 lists of 11 formulas each (1 for each feature)
   [image]
2. train with 1000 dataframes of 11 columns each
   [image]

I want to apply the rpart function on each dataframe using the formulas of each list in imputemodel. How do I loop this 1000 times without having to write each line like below?

```
 list1=list(lapply(imputemodel[[1]],rpart,data=train[[1]]))
 list2=list(lapply(imputemodel[[2]],rpart,data=train[[2]]))
 list3=list(lapply(imputemodel[[3]],rpart,data=train[[3]]))

 ...

 list1000 = ...

 combined list <- c(list1, list2, list3, ...., list1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Map` :

```
combined_list <- Map(rpart, imputemodel, data = train)
```

With `lapply` you can iterate over the index and subset model and data.

```
combined_list <- lapply(seq_along(imputemodel), function(i) 
                        rpart(imputemodel[[i]], train[[i]]))
```

Comment: I tried that and I got an error: Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula

Comment: `rpart` expects a formula object and I guess you have models in `imputemodel`. Does this really work for you? `list1=lapply(imputemodel[[1]],rpart,data=train[[1]])`

Comment: My bad, the impute model list has formulas. I have edited the question

Comment: You can try `combined_list <- Map(function(x, y) Map(rpart, x, y), imputemodel, train)`. Are you sure you want to apply `rpart` function only on one column?

Comment: @lypnesum Did you try `combined_list <- Map(function(x, y) Map(rpart, x, y), imputemodel, train)` ? What does it return?